# C# Implicit casting to List<T> returns runtime error

Tags: c#, operator-keyword, implicit, implicit-conversion

I have a class similar to the following that uses an internal List:

```
public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
        private List<T> _lstInternal;
        public MyList()
        {
            _lstInternal = new List<T>();
        }
        public static implicit operator List<T>(MyList<T> toCast)
        {
            return toCast._lstInternal;
        }

}
```

When I try to pass `MyList<object>` to a function that takes a `List<object>`, I get an InvalidCastException. Why?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? I'm using 4.0 and was able to do what you're describing here without an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just derive from `List<T>`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, then users of the class would be able to mutate the list or access it via an indexer. Perhaps the author does not want to expose that functionality.

Comment: I did not get the exception using .NET 2.0, may be you can post the lines where you have the exception?

Comment: @Anthony Pegram He already does expose it via the public implicit cast operator. He only hides the methods similar to an explicit interface implementation.

Comment: Did not consider how we was actually implementing his implicit cast. I don't like it. Forget I said anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the class you described, the following code worked for me:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   MyList<object> foo = new MyList<object>();

   MyMethod(foo);
}

static void MyMethod(List<object> things)
{
   // No InvalidCastException when called...
}
```

The only thing I changed from the `MyList<T>` class you posted in your question was adding the following implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return _lstInternal.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return _lstInternal.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Not really sure why you're getting an exception, except as I mentioned in my comment, I'm using C# version 4.0. What version are you using?

Comment: Actually my problem was that I was passing the object to a different project, which was not aware of the MyList class, and therefore it didn't know how to cast it. So now I am just casting MyList before sending it to the other project.